# Passing correct format date in Elasticsearch "strict_date_time_no_millis"

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, format

I am trying to add the date in the ElasticSearch (v6.8.14) database where the type of the index is date and the format is "strict_date_time_no_millis" using the python API (v7.14.0).
I tried pushing the date using the format the following code `datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`, but it throws the following error:

````
RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [doc.metadata.timestamp] of type [date] in document with id '######'")
```.
````

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert the date format to `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` and the problem should be solved.

The following document should be referred:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html